# Python 'str' object is not callable Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, string, callable

I am currently writing a trade game, where users connect to a server, then trade with one another and earn money, etc.
But when I try

```
if(input.lower() == 'sell'):
        sMaterial = raw_input('Material: ')
        if(sMaterial.lower() == 'gold'):
            sAmount = int(input('Enter amount: '))
            if(gold >= sAmount):
                mon = mon + (100 * sAmount)
            else:
                print 'You do not have enough', sMaterial
```

It throws the error

```
> sell
Material: gold
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 119, in <module>
    sAmount = int(input('Enter amount: '))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I am using Linux, Python version 2.7.3, with Geany development environment.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

This line:

```
if(input.lower() == 'sell'):
```

tells me that you must have bound the name `input` to a string at some point.  So when you call

```
sAmount = int(input('Enter amount: '))
```

you're trying to pass the argument `'Enter amount: '` to the *string* `input`, hence: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.  Since it looks like you're using Python 2, you should probably be using `raw_input` anyhow, but this is another reason not to rebind the builtin names.

Answer (score 3):

You have overwritten the `input` function with a variable holding some data.  Somewhere you did `input = ...`.  (You can see in the first line of your code that you're doing `input.lower()`.)  The solution is to change the part of your code that does this.  Don't give your variables the same names as builtin functions or types.

Answer (score 1):

you should do

```
sAmount = int(raw_input('Enter amount: '))
```

instead of

```
sAmount = int(input('Enter amount: '))
```

and you may want to do some exception handling somewhere in there too :)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I saw the other posts here too and they helped. I am sorry I did not notice that.